# Align "Table of Contents" heading to the left

Tags: table-of-contents

Really simple question: I want to align the "Table of Contents" heading to the left, not the actual list of contents, the "Table of Contents" heading.

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame]{llncs}
\usepackage{llncsdoc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@author[2]{}
\renewcommand*\l@title[2]{}
\makeatletter
\title{...}
\author{...}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\email{...}
\end{center}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract here
\end{abstract}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip -1cm}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents*
\endgroup

...


\end{document}
```

Right now, it looks like this:

[image]

I want the title "Table of Contents" to be left-aligned, just like "1 - Introduction". How can I do it?

Comment: Which class of document do you use?

Comment: Welcome! By default, it is formatted as an unnumbered chapter (for `book`) or section (for `article`) etc. So you need to show us the code you are using to make it come out non-default.

Comment: Right, sorry! I edited the question

Comment: You are submitting to Lecture notes in computer science, are you sure you are allowed to do any layout changes?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to include `llncsdoc`?

Comment: Yes I need to include `llncsdoc`, it's the template suggested, however I am allowed to change some visual contents, like the Table of Contents. But if this is not possible to change because I'm using `llncsdoc` then it's fine! It's just a matter of preference

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you load the `tocloft` package (`\usepackage{tocloft}`) and issue the instruction

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Large\bfseries}
```

in the preamble. To change the font size choose, e.g., `\huge` or `\large` instead of `\Large`.

Here's the full code that aligns the Table of Contents header to the left. (Note that while the header if flush-left, the entries are indented by a certain amount -- which is the default with or without the `tocloft` package.)

```
\documentclass[envcountsame]{llncs}
\usepackage{llncsdoc,graphicx,acronym,url,verbatim}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Large\bfseries}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=black}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*\l@author[2]{}
%\renewcommand*\l@title[2]{}
%\makeatletter
%\title{...}
%\author{...}

\begin{document}

%\begin{center}
%\email{...}
%\end{center}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here
\end{abstract}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip -1cm}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\bigskip\hrule  % just to illustrate width of text block

\section{A}
\section{B}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't load the `tocloft` package, I always get an error `Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \authcount`. Do I need to include it in a specific part of the preamble ?

Comment: @riotvan - It should be loaded before `hyperref`.

Comment: Nope, still get the same error.

Comment: @riotvan - I'm afraid I don't have access to the file `llncsdoc.sty`. Where might it be obtained from?

Comment: you can get the styles here: http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0, its the `llncs2e.zip` file

Comment: @riotvan - Thanks for the link. I've posted a full working example which, when compiled, aligns the "Table of Contents" header to the left.